# Authenticating in Azure SQL Database using Azure Active Directory B2C

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

I'm having problems with authenticating to Azure SQL Database through Azure Active Directory.

I am pretty much following the instructions I found here:
[ https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-aad-authentication/ ][Connecting to SQL Database By Using Azure Active Directory Authentication]

I am able to authenticate with Azure Active Directory using localhost and OpenID. I am able to sign up, sign in, and log out. I used "fake@genericcompany.com" (actual email changed) as the user, and I can get an authorization_code and id_token by signing in. I have also added "fake@genericcompany.com" as the Active Directory admin of my SQL Database, and added my computer's IP address to the firewall settings.

I have tried to authenticate with "fake@genericcompany.com" using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, but I received this error message:

```
===================================

Cannot connect to abc.database.windows.net.

===================================

Failed to authenticate the user fake@genericcompany.com in Active Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword).
Error code 0xCAA90018; state 10
Could not discover a user realm. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=0&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Server Name: abc.database.windows.net
Error Number: 0
Severity: 11
State: 0
Procedure: ADALGetAccessToken


------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType server)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()
```

Here is my fake Azure setup:

```
Azure Active Directory B2C
Directory domain: xyz.onmicrosoft.com

Azure SQL Server
Name: abc.database.windows.net
Server version: V12
Number of databases: 1
Database name: def
Dababase pricing tier: S0 Standard
```

I have also set up the subscription that contains the SQL Database and server to be within the same Active Directory stated above.

I have read some stuff about "contained databases" and "contained database users", and I might need 2 databases: a "master database" and a "user database", but I don't understand all this, especially in the context of Azure SQL Database. Here is one of the links that I read, but don't fully understand:

[ https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff929188.aspx ][Contained Database Users - Making Your Database Portable]

I'll post the other links below, since SO won't let me post more than 2 links.

Comment: Here are the other links:  [ https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff929071.aspx ][Contained Databases]  [ https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-security-guidelines/ ][Azure SQL Database security guidelines and limitations]

Comment: **Update**

I have pictures:

[Login attempt 1][ http://i.stack.imgur.com/qiqUg.png ]

[Login attempt 2][ http://i.stack.imgur.com/8u9oZ.png ]

[Error message][ http://i.stack.imgur.com/MqwJS.png ]

The error message using my fake, non-existent information is the same as when I use my actual "Server name" and "Username", so maybe that means something?

Answer (score 3):

As we documented in [ https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-aad-authentication/ ][Connecting to SQL Database By Using Azure Active Directory Authentication], the MSA accounts and guest accounts are not supported in the current version ( see below).
Only native and integrated domain Azure AD accounts are currently supported for Azure SQL DB.

From the doc... (see Azure AD features and limitations)

Microsoft accounts (for example outlook.com, hotmail.com, live.com) or other guest accounts (for example gmail.com, yahoo.com) are not supported. If you can login to https://login.live.com using the account and password, then you are using a Microsoft account which is not supported for Azure AD authentication for Azure SQL Database.

Thanks
Mirek

Mirek Sztajno, Senior PM SQL Server security team

Comment: Thanks Mirek; do you have information about the native and integrated domain Azure AD accounts that you are talking about? Would this mean I can't take a web app, from Azure Web Services or an outside server like "localhost", authenticate via Azure Active Directory, and access our SQL Database that way? We are trying to use Azure Active Directory to authenticate all web apps in our company.

Comment: As for Microsoft & guest accounts, I used fake@gmail.com as an example, but thank you, I will clarify by changing the domain name, to fake@genericcompany.com. In our Active Directory settings, under "Identity provider", I have selected "Local accounts" to be "Email", and I have not set up any "Social identity providers", which has these providers listed: Microsoft Account, Google, Facebook, LinkedIn, and Amazon. Do you think switching the Identity provider to "Username" will help? Any other things I should try?

Answer (score 0):

Bellow I collected a few Azure AD links (including build-in domains) for you to go over 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-add-domain/ 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect-accounts-permissions/

The scenario you describe should work as long as you do not use MS accounts or guest accounts. You can create your own native domain with a list of users (with users&passwords), or federate your company domain with Azure AD using ADFS and allowing to use Windows credentials.
Feel free to use our help alias SQLAzureADAuth@microsoft.com for further questions on this topic.

Thanks,

Mirek